# Unexpected output of C code

Tags: c++, c

What would be the output of this program ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int x=20,y=30,z=10;
    int i=x<y<z;
    printf("%d",i);
    getch();
}
```

Actually `i=20<30<10`, so the condition is false and the value of `i` should be 0 but `i` equals 1. Why?

Comment: `void main` **RAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHH**

Comment: @pmg: You love doing that, huh? :D

Comment: Because one is less than ten?

Comment: @Xeo: hopefully I will get through to as many people as possible :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This `int i=x<y<z;` doesn't work the way you intended.

The effect is `int i=(x<y)<z;`, where `x<y`is evaluated first, and the value `true` is then compared to `z`.

---

Pascal points out below that in C the result of the comparison is `1` instead of `true`. However, the C++ `true` is implicitly converted to `1` in the next comparison, so the result is the same.

Comment: value of first expression is true that means 1. so 1<10(ie 1<z) would also be true........ is am right

Comment: @learnfromothers - That is correct. The last comparison is again `true` which is converted to 1 when stored in `i`.

Comment: The question's title says "C code". In C, `x<y` has type `int`. `true`, which in any case is not a core feature but a macro that expands to `1` in `stdbool.h`, does not enter the picture here.

Comment: @Pascal - The question is tagged C++ as well. You may read my answer in view of that.

Answer (score 5):

The comparison operators don't work like that.  Your program is equivalent to:

```
i = (x < y) < z;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
i = (x < y);
i = i < z;
```

After the first operation, `i == 1`.  So the second operation is equivalent to:

```
i = 1 < 10;
```

You need to rewrite your statement as:

```
i = (x < y) && (y < z);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<` operator has left-to-right associativity. Therefore `x<y<z` will do `(x<y)<z`. The result of the first parenthesis is 1, 1 is smaller than 10, so you'll get 1.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works. It's better to see with parenthesis:

```
int i = (x<y)<z;
```

Now, first `x<y` is evaluated. It's true, `20<30`, and true is `1` as an integer. `1<z` is then true again.

Answer (score 1):

Its precedence is from left to right. Thats is why it is like

20<30 = true
1<10 TRUE

SO FINALLY TRUE

Answer (score 0):

Actually `<` is left-associative, so first, 20<30 is evaluated (giving 1 usually), then 1 is less than 10.

Answer (score 0):

The output of "1" is correct. This is evaluated as `(20<30) < 10`, which is `1 < 10`, which is 1.

The problem is that you are comparing a boolean value to an integer value which in most cases doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `<` [associates](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) from left to right.

So `x < y < z` is same as `( x < y ) < z`

Your expression evaluates as:

```
  ( x < y ) < z
= ( 20 < 30 ) < 10
= ( 1 ) < 10
= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

< is evaulated from left to right, so 20<30 is true, or one, which is less than 10.